# Fetch multi output from SQL Transformation at Informatica

Tags: sql, oracle, transformation, informatica

I want to fetch query result from informatica SQL Transformation.
I get a sql query to an input port(QUERY) also want to fetch sysdate

```
SELECT (~QUERY~),SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

But it does not let me to fetch such a result as 2 output column.
When I write

```
~QUERY~
```

it is giving me result, but I need 2nd or 3rd column.

Thanks

Comment: what is the issue you are facing when you have multiple columns in select? Did you create the corresponding output ports in SQL transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was working with 9.5.1, have problem with 9.6.1

```
SELECT (~QUERY~),SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

You can put as statement to assign column to output port. Assume that outport port is RESULT and DATETIME

```
SELECT (~QUERY~) RESULT ,SYSDATE DATETIME FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first try putting sysdate into the query as one of the columns rather than encapsulating and selecting from dual

e.g. SELECT A.COLUMN, A.COLUMN2, SYSDATE, A.COLUMN3 FROM TABLENAME A WHERE CONDITION

Then if you want a multi row return you can use an inline lookup configured to return multiple rows (cant select from dual in a lookup). The one gotcha is that you must be on powercenter 9.1 or higher... otherwise you'll need to put that query in a source qualifier and use a joiner to bring it into the main pipeline. Why sysdate from the database rather than the native informatica SYSTIMESTAMP function?